# Why does merging these arrays cause an error?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

My front-end and back-end code is listed below. It's working perfectly. And from this page I'm sending 2 arrays to another page. There I want to merge the arrays and insert into a MySQL table. Here it my front page.

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $team_id=$_GET['team_id'];
    $sql1=mysql_query("select members from team where team_id='$team_id'");
    $sql=mysql_query("select user_id,full_name from users where school_id= '1'");

    while($array=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $x[] = $array['user_id'];
    }
    echo "</br>";
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $member=unserialize($row1['members']);
    echo "<form action='ad_team_mem_db.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<select name='mem[]' size='25' multiple='multiple'>";
    foreach(array_diff_assoc($x ,$member) as $item)
    {
        $sqlf=mysql_query("select user_id,full_name from users where school_id=1 and user_id='$item'");
        if($roww=mysql_fetch_array($sqlf)){
            echo "<option value='".$roww['user_id']."'>".$roww['full_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    echo "</select></br>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='$member' name='member[]'>";
    echo "<input type='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</br>";
?>
```

And this is my backend page. In this page I couldn't merge 2 arrays.

```
<?
    include("db.php");
    $mem=$_POST['mem'];
    $member=$_POST['member'];
    **$members = array_merge ($member, $mem);**
?>
```

Error message,

> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in C:\AppServ\www\teen\ad_team_mem_db.php on line 5

Comment: What do $_POST['mem'] and $_POST['member'] look like when they hit your backend page?

Comment: it showing only the $mem values!!! its not showing any $member value !!

Comment: What is the value of $member in first script?

Comment: `$sql1=mysql_query("select members from team where team_id='$team_id'");    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $member=unserialize($row1['members']);`

Answer (score 1):

At the point you do this:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$member' name='member[]'>";
```

`$member` is a PHP array, and what you'll end up in the form will look like:

```
<input type='hidden' value='Array' name='member[]'>
```

which upon POSTing will be a simple string, which is why your array_merge is failing.

Comment: OOps soo whats is the solution to that?

Comment: Now i have chaged how u suggest `<input type='hidden' value='Array' name='member[]'>` but still not working

Comment: I didn't say to change it to that, I said that's what your code is generating.

Comment: whoaa is it !! im realy sorry im not expert in php !! Please give me a solution !! what i wanna pass there !!

Comment: I have put total code on this page !! Actually i wanna pass the $member array to next page thats it !! Please give me an Idea !!

Comment: Yes, I see the code, and I still have no idea what it's trying to accomplish

Comment: there are members in table as arrays, if i wanna insert more members to same array thn, im not showing who ever already member, thats the scenario here goin

Comment: Then I suggest you fix you database design and normalize it, store the group members in a seperate table, which eliminates the need for your serialize stuff. That way, if you delete a member, you don't have to update however many fields to remove that member from the serialized data - it'd just happen "magically" as part of a properly normalized design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to unserialise the POST vars before merging.

Comment: No Itried like this..but its not working..`<?
 include("db.php");
 $member=unserialize($_POST['members']);
 $member=$_POST['member'];
 $members = array_merge ($member, $mem);

?>`

Comment: and $mem is working , I checked that within foreach() method, only the problem in $member

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$members = array_merge ((array) $member, (array) $mem);
```

Comment: Yeah U did half write i think that im receiving only the values of $mem ,Plese give some try

Comment: what I see from your code is that there is no need of of array [] in your html since you are giving many options to user but only one input gets selected in the end by the user